# Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 9464)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**I don't know why this eror I wrote it from a tutorial but It's happend**

*this is view.py file*
[here](https://dpaste.org/Ffqt)

```
import view as view
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.views import View

# Create your views here.
from teams.models import Team

class HomePageView(View):
    def get(self,requests):
        all_teams = Team.objects.all()
        context = {"teams": all_teams}
        return render(requests,"teamlist.html",context)
```

**this is my admin.py file**
this is my admin.py file:[here](https://dpaste.org/5jZs#L8)

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from teams.models import Team, Player, GameScore

admin.site.register(Team)
admin.site.register(Player)
admin.site.register(GameScore)
```

*that's my first question on stack over flow I don't know I ask True or not . I just need some help :)*

Comment: Can you add the full error stacktrace, so we can see what line raises the error?

Comment: yes , mr.Ralf can you give me more explain what do you mean ?

Comment: I don't know how to explain what a stacktrace is in few words, so here is a link with explanation and examples https://realpython.com/python-traceback/#what-is-a-python-traceback

Comment: You can look at other PYTHON questions here on StackOverflow to see other examples